# Bedeuten "anhören" und "zuhören" dasselbe?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-choice, difference

Sind die folgenden Sätze richtig? Und wenn ja, haben sie dieselbe Bedeutung?

> Sie hörte der Diskussion schweigend zu.
>
> Sie hörte die Diskussion schweigend an.

Comment: There are slight differents in connotation, imho; see my answer.

Comment: The second sentence is unidiomatic, although not incomprehensible. _anhören_ is either reflexive with _sich_ and dative object or, with slightly different meaning, requires an animate object.

Answer (score 12):

The words mostly mean the same thing but they are used differently with respect to grammar.

> sich etw. anhören
> jmd. wird angehört
>
> jmdm. zuhören
> jmdm. wird zugehört

Note:

- The active form of "anhören" is (mostly) used for things (including e.g. bands, or things said by people).
- The passive form of "anhören" is used in formal setting, e.g. in court ("Anhörung").
- The active form of "zuhören" is (mostly) used for listening to people.
- the passive form of "zuhören" is rarely used.

For instance,

> man hört sich eine Rede an

but

> man hört einem Redner zu.

When describing activities, the active forms can often be used interchangeably (provided you rearrange the sentence accordingly); there is, however, a slight difference in connotation. "Zuhören" is more active and suggests comprehension/interaction in some sense: you learn something, give an answer or provide a "service" by listening. "Anhören", on the other hand, is rather the physical activity without any consequence. Compare, for instance:

> "Ich habe mir angehört, was er zu sagen hatte, und bin gegangen."
> <sub>I listened to what he had to say and left.</sub>

with

> "Ich habe ihr gut zugehört und verstanden, was sie meinte."
> <sub>I listened carefully and understood what she meant.</sub>

Some more example sentences:

- "Die Verteidigung [im Gericht] wird angehört."
- "Ich höre mir die neue Platte an."
- "Muss ich mir das wirklich anhören?"
- "Hörst du mir zu?"
- "Wenn du gut zuhörst, lernst du etwas."
- "Hättest du [der Person vorhin] besser zugehört, führen wir nicht im Kreis."
- "Professor Besserwisser redet so monoton, ich kann ihm nicht zuhören ohne einzuschlafen"

Comment: +1 *jemandem* (und nicht jemanden) zuhören!? echt? Wieder was gelernt.

Comment: @c.p. Indeed! Thanks for noting that I should add the case to the first listing; it didn't even occur to me that there may be an issue. The curse of the native speaker...

Comment: Actually I don't think you have to. I was actually surprised because I've always thought *zuhören* was with accusative. Aber das sind halt meine sprachlichen Bildungslücken...

Comment: Upon reflection, I *think* "jmdn. anhören" is valid, too, in the court setting. I'll boldly claim that it's old and no longer used (except maybe in special, ritualised circumstances).

Comment: anhören could mean to just endure the talking without actively listening and understanding what was said. zuhören is always listening closely and understanding was was said.

Answer (score 2):

Die Sätze sind grammatikalisch korrekt, ja. Mit demselben Nomen haben sie auch dieselbe Bedeutung; „einer Diskussion zuhören“ wird aber im Sprachgebrauch nicht verwendet.

Bezüglich der Bedeutung: Bei deinem Beispiel heißen „zuhören“ und „anhören“ dasselbe. Aber „man hört sich Musik an“ oder „hört zu, wie etwas gesagt wird“. Etwas „anhören“ ist fast immer mit Absicht, „zuhören“ kann auch unbeabsichtigt sein.

Comment: Ich würde nicht so weit gehen und behaupten, dass "zuhören" in dem Kontext nicht verwendet wird. Ich würde nicht mal sagen, dass es weniger gängig ist. Ich höre bei Diskussion im Nachbarbüro oft nur "zu", weil ich einfach nicht weghören kann ;)

Comment: Du hörst **bei** der Diskussion/dem Gespräch/der Unterhaltung zu. Aber dass jemand der Diskussion zuhört sowie man einem Redner zuhört habe ich noch nie gehört. Kann aber auch wieder an der Region liegen; und das ist auch nur sehr speziell für das Wort Diskussion.
EDIT: WIe auch @Arlecchino12 schon sagt: man schaut **sich** eine Talkshow im Fernsehen an oder hört **sich** eine Reportage im Radio an.

Comment: Naja, oder man hört zu. "Hörst du denn überhaupt zu?" wird ja dann doch oft verwendet. Geschweige denn, dass anhören wie in der Anhörung sowieso wieder was anderes heißt und nicht einfach gegen zuhören ausgetauscht werden kann.

Answer (score 2):

Ja, beide Sätze meinen das gleiche. Mit einem kleinen Unterschied: Meiner Meinung nach fehlt noch ein "sich" im zweiten Satz.
"Sie hörte sich die Diskussion schweigend an"

Comment: This is a valid correction, but not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

generalised:

zuhören: "listening to somebody"
anhören: "listening to something"

(Generalised! Of course "something" can also be a speech and "somebody" can make noices or music etc pp!)

Also there is a "direction" in zuhören. "zu-hören". 
So it often means "I am (listening and) paying attention (to you)!"